# how to unstack a dataframe based on a condition?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following setup.

```
   a foo  b foo   c foo    Set

 0 first  second  third  fourth
```

The goal is to merge all columns with `foo` in their header name and output the following:

```
   All_foo    Set

0   first    fourth

1   second 

2   third
```

I tried the following:

```
df2 = df.unstack().reset_index(drop=True).rename('All_foo').to_frame()
```

This gives me one single column with all the values merged. How can I make the unstacking 
process to be based on a condition so that I can get the output above?

Comment: `a foo`, `b foo` are they columns and `first` , `second` etc data?

Comment: yes thats correct!

Comment: ok, then why does only the first one gets `Set` as `fourth`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what name of columns contains **foo** with [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), then use [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) 
where this condition is not met:

```
cols_melt = [*df.columns[~df.columns.str.contains('foo')]]
#cols_melt = df.columns[~df.columns.str.contains('foo')].tolist()
new_df = df.melt(cols_melt,value_name = 'All foo')[['All foo']+ cols_melt]
print(new_df)
  All foo     Set
0   first  fourth
1  second  fourth
2   third  fourth
```

---

**Setting NaN values:**

```
new_df[cols_melt] = df[cols_melt]
print(new_df)
  All foo     Set
0   first  fourth
1  second     NaN
2   third     NaN
```

Comment: such answers are fast to write but hard to understand

Comment: I think a two-line python code with the documentation is self explanatory. @YOLO

Comment: awesome! can you tell me what * and ~ are doing? or if you can point me to some kind of documentation?

Comment: this unpack the columns index , but if you want to learn more about see:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/use-of-args-and-kwargs/3394898#3394898 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters

Answer (score 0):

I would use `filter` to slice out columns having `foo` assign it to `df1`. Process `df1` to a series by using `stack` and `reset_index`. Finally, `concat` the result back to non-`foo` columns

```
df1 = df.filter(like='foo')
df_final = pd.concat([df1.stack().rename('all foo').reset_index(drop=True), 
                      df.drop(df1.columns,1)], axis=1)

Out[1321]:
  all foo     Set
0   first  fourth
1  second     NaN
2   third     NaN
```